# Current timestamp in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I am using PHP to print the current timestamp using `time()` and I have a MySQL column which stores the date, which I am converting to a timestamp using `strtotime()`. However, when I print the converted values, I have a one hour difference between them. The real difference is in seconds. What's wrong?

Comment: What's your timezone setting in PHP, and what's the timezone setting in MySQL? There is your answer.

Comment: Bet the server you're running the commands on (or the mysql config) is an hour off.

Comment: @Wrikken: Could have earned you at least 10 points if you posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming they both run on the same physical server, it is probably a timezone mismatch.

You can check the timezone on your MySQL server by running the following query in the MySQL console:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
```

And on your PHP page by running a script with:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

Once you figure out which one is wrong, you should be able to fix this by editing my.cnf or php.ini.

You can also change the default timezone on runtime using [date_default_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)().

Answer (score 2):

[Set your timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) before inserting your times

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); // Whatever your timezone is

mysql_query("INSERT
            INTO table
            (date)
            VALUES
            (" . time() . ")") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the PHP [strftime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) function, as it does take local timezones into account. You may be running into a daylight savings time issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function to get the current epoch time:

```
INSERT INTO mytable SET tstamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```